# Can updating a field on parent based on a child criteria be done without code?

Tags: process-builder, field-update

In this scenario we have a custom object called proposal which is a child to the contact object.

I need to update fields on the contact object (parent) when one edits a Proposal document (child). If there is multiple child documents, I need the one with a specific status "waiting for approval" to update the parent and not any other child documents.

Can this be done with process builder or another way without using code? I tried PB but I wasn't successful. Is this doable?

Comment: You can use a flow to update related record in more complicated ways. Have you tried that?

Comment: Not yet. The reason is that in the back of my mind, flows aren't as dependable and that is why I don't know admins in my circles that use it. They'd just as well go to triggers. Do you have an opinion on this?

Comment: My main point is to avoid mix-n-match. Use Process Builder *or* use triggers. Trying to mix the two is complicated and can easily cause governor limit issues. As long as you stick to either/or, you'll be fine.